# Find $P(n+1)$ where $P(x)$ is a $n$ degree polynomial.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A polynomial $P(x)$ of $n$ degree satisfies $P(k)=2^k$ for $k = 0,1,2,3......,n$.  Find the value of $P(n+1)$.

How can I proceed in solving such problems.

Comment: You have degree $n$ and $n+1$ particular values. So set it all up with $n+1$ arbitrary coefficients and plug in.

Comment: Just determine the interpolating polynomial. I do not think that there is any shortcut here

Comment: The other two comments suggest the obvious brute-force approach. There might be some clever approach using forward differencing. Not sure; not feeling very clever tonight.

Comment: Another possible way: Use Lagrange-Polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Answer (score 0):

$P_n(x+1) - P_n(x) = P_{n-1}(x)$

$G(n) = P_n(n+1)$

$G_n = P_n(n+1) - P_n(n) + P_n(n) = 2^n + G_{n-1}$

So, is the simple close formula